# You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error. Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular

So I am trying the run the environment scripts and APIs for the development side of the website my team is building and every time I run `ng build` for each environment API this error pops up:
[Example of the error that is being produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G9S6.jpg)

now here is my pack.json file:

```
{
  "name": "clark-gateway",
  "version": "1.0.0-beta.4.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run gulp-tsc",
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/gulp tsc",
    "gulp-tsc": "node_modules/.bin/gulp start",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/tslint --project ./src/**",
    "pack": "npm run build && cp ./package.json ./dist && cd ./dist && zip -r ../dist.zip  ./* & cd ..",
    "zip": "cp ./package.json ./dist && cd ./dist && zip -r ../dist.zip  ./* & cd ..",
    "deploy": "eb deploy CLARK-Gateway-Production --label CLARK-Gateway-v$(node -p \"require('./package.json').version\")",
    "document": "node_modules/.bin/typedoc --out ./docs/ ./src/"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express-jwt": "0.0.38",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^7.2.3",
    "@types/raven": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.39",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.39",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.32",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.7",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.9.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cyber4all/clark-entity": "^2.1.0-beta.0.4",
    "@cyber4all/clark-taxonomy": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.33",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.147.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-http-proxy": "^1.1.0",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.0",
    "helmet": "^3.6.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^2.0.1",
    "raven": "^2.3.0",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "serverless-http": "^1.5.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint"
  ],
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all"
  }
}
```

Things that I have tried:
- I have deleted the node modules folder numerous times (3 times to be exact)
- npm installed 3 times also deleted the pack-lock.json file 
- Also I did the recommended commands and it gave me more errors such as

> PS C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service> ng
>   build
>       Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
>       Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
>           at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:37:19)
>           at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:24:21)
>           at BuildCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:180:32)
>           at BuildCommand. (C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:47:25)
>           at Generator.next ()
>           at C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:7:71
>           at new Promise ()
>           at __awaiter (C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:3:12)
>           at BuildCommand.initialize (C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:46:16)
>           at Object. (C:\Clark-Development\CLARK-Environment-master\cart-service\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:87:23)

This error occurs after I execute the command `npm install --save-dev @angular/core@latest`

Comment: It sounds like you have now successfully installed @angular/core. The error you're seeing now is because angular CLI can't find the `angular.json` config file in your project. Does it exist? Bear in mind with older versions of the CLI it was called `angular-cli.json`

Comment: I see what you mean now, I looked at one of working files and it has the angular-cli.json file. How do you propose I install this?

Comment: Why does your front end Angular project depend on express?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was running the wrong commands, which explains why its saying it needs angular-cli to use the command I was using. I used `npm start` which worked flawlessly